# Authentication needed error with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube-api, asihttprequest, gdata-api

I have do many googling but I can't find any understandable tutorial of ASIHttpRequest and Youtube API. I also ask many question on Stackoverflow and other forums but no one can helps.
I try to get the favorite video list from youtube. I have sign in success and got the accesstoken. I set it to the request header with key Authorization but Youtube always return the error:

> Respond failed with message: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain
>   Code=3 "Authentication needed" UserInfo=0x933b980
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication needed}

Here is my codes:

```
#define CONNECTION_GET_FAVORITE_LIST @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites"

- (void) getFavoriteList{


  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:CONNECTION_GET_FAVORITE_LIST];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[@" Bearer "  stringByAppendingString:<accesstoken goes here>];
    request 
    [request startAsynchronous];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString* respondMessage = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"Respond complete with message: %@",respondMessage);
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSString* respondMessage = [request error];
        NSLog(@"Respond failed with message: %@",respondMessage);
    }];
    [request release];
}
```

UPDATE: when I try to use method GET and set the accesstoken on the link as: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites?v=2&access_token=<accesstoken>`, youtube throw the error:

> Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
>
> Error 401

Please helps me to resolve this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried testing out the same request from the command line using curl as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API just to check if the token is valid?

Answer (score 1):

Fristly don't use `ASIHTTPRequest` use `AFNetworking`. but here u don't need anyone of this.

Now your request needs `authentication and authorization` to `gdata` for requesting to get `feed` in `youtube`.

**EDIT** : Refer [gtm-oauth2](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction) link.

Refer [GData Youtube API Documenttaion](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) link.